# Limit $\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\sum_{r=1}^{k-1}\zeta\left(2r\right)\frac{\left(-1\right)^{r+k}}{\left(2k-2r-1\right)!}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, summation, riemann-zeta

I am interested in finding this limit and the answer seems to be:
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\sum_{r=1}^{k-1}\zeta\left(2r\right)\frac{\left(-1\right)^{r+k}}{\left(2k-2r-1\right)!}\right)=-\sin1$$
I kind of have a method for this but that is based on how I came across this series.


I would love to see other solutions that are not based on how it was derived.

EDIT:

Also as a side note it seems that,
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\sum_{r=1}^{k-1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k+r}}{\left(2k-2r-1\right)!}\right)=-\sin1$$
The series without $\zeta$ equals the same.

EDIT 2:

I realized we could first simplify a bit by $r\to k-1+1-r=k-r$
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\sum_{r=1}^{k-1}\zeta\left(2k-2r\right)\frac{\left(-1\right)^{r}}{\left(2r-1\right)!}\right)=-\sin1$$
Also notice that,
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\sum_{r=1}^{k-1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{r}}{\left(2r-1\right)!}\right)=-\sin1$$
So I thought lets try it on other series,

Numerically,
$$\lim_{k\to \infty}\left(\sum_{r=0}^{k}\frac{\zeta\left(2k-2r\right)}{r!}\right)=e$$

Also, notice that.
$$\lim_{k\to \infty}\left(\sum_{r=0}^{k}\frac{1}{r!}\right)=e$$
This is kind of interesting, shouldn't the $\zeta$ term affect the summation?

Comment: How did you derive the limit? This will help us avoid writing solutions using the same derivation.

Comment: Very nice problem ! (+1)

Comment: Just use [Tannery's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannery%27s_theorem).

Comment: @Gary Thank You, I will check that out, it's my first time hearing about this theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## ORIGINAL   ANSWER

To put it succinctly.
\begin{align*}
\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}{\zeta \left( 2\left( N-n \right) \right) \frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n}{\left( 2n-1 \right) !}}
=&\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{k^{2n}}{k^{2N}}}\frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n}{\left( 2n-1 \right) !}}
\\
=&\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^{2N-1}}}\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}{\frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n}{\left( 2n-1 \right) !}}k^{2n-1}
\\
=&\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^{2N-1}}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n}{\left( 2n-1 \right) !}}k^{2n-1}
\\
=&-\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin \left( k \right)}{k^{2N-1}}}=-\sin \left( 1 \right) 
\end{align*}
If you found this a bit too handwavy, I could provide the solution in greater detail.

## EDIT

I shall provide a more rigorous proof here.
To start with, we rewrite the sum in terms of the definition of riemann zeta function. So we have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}{\zeta \left( 2\left( N-n \right) \right) \frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n}{\left( 2n-1 \right) !}}=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{k^{2n}}{k^{2N}}}\frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n}{\left( 2n-1 \right) !}}
$$
We can interchange the sums if each terms in the finite sum converges, which is obvious in this case. Therefore
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{k^{2n}}{k^{2N}}}\frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n}{\left( 2n-1 \right) !}}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^{2N-1}}}\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}{\frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n}{\left( 2n-1 \right) !}}k^{2n-1}
$$
Now we have to proof that
$$
\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^{2N-1}}}\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}{\frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n}{\left( 2n-1 \right) !}}k^{2n-1}=0
$$
Since we have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n}{\left( 2n-1 \right) !}}k^{2n-1}=\sin \left( k \right) 
$$
Which converges, by something Cauchy (Cannot remember the exact name)
$\forall \varepsilon >0, \exists N\in \mathbb{N}\,\,\mathrm{s}.\mathrm{t}.$
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}{\frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n}{\left( 2n-1 \right) !}}k^{2n-1}<\frac{\varepsilon}{\zeta \left( 2 \right)}<\frac{\varepsilon}{\zeta \left( 2N-1 \right)}
\\
\Rightarrow &\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^{2N-1}}}\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}{\frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n}{\left( 2n-1 \right) !}}k^{2n-1}<\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^{2N-1}}}\frac{\varepsilon}{\zeta \left( 2N-1 \right)}=\varepsilon 
\end{align*}
Which proves the claim. Hence
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^{2N-1}}}\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}{\frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n}{\left( 2n-1 \right) !}}k^{2n-1}
\\
=&\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^{2N-1}}}\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}{\frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n}{\left( 2n-1 \right) !}}k^{2n-1}+0
\\
=&\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^{2N-1}}}\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}{\frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n}{\left( 2n-1 \right) !}}k^{2n-1}+\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^{2N-1}}}\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}{\frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n}{\left( 2n-1 \right) !}}k^{2n-1}
\\
=&\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^{2N-1}}}\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}{\frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n}{\left( 2n-1 \right) !}}k^{2n-1}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^{2N-1}}}\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}{\frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n}{\left( 2n-1 \right) !}}k^{2n-1} \right) 
\\
=&\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^{2N-1}}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n}{\left( 2n-1 \right) !}}k^{2n-1}
\\
=&-\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin \left( k \right)}{k^{2N-1}}}
\end{align*}
Now, notice that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\left| \frac{\sin \left( k \right)}{k^{2N-1}} \right|}\leqslant \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^{2N-1}}}=\zeta \left( 2N-1 \right) 
$$
Meaning the sum converge absolutely, implying the sum converges. So we only need to prove
$$
\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \left| \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin \left( k \right)}{k^{2N-1}}} \right|=\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \left| \sin \left( 1 \right) -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin \left( k \right)}{k^{2N-1}}} \right|=0
$$
The gist to prove this is along these lines
\begin{align*}
&\forall \varepsilon >0, \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \,\,  \mathrm{s}.\mathrm{t}.
\\
&\left| \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin \left( k \right)}{k^{2N-1}}} \right|\leqslant \left| \sum_{k=2}^N{\frac{\sin \left( k \right)}{k^{2N-1}}} \right|+\left| \sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin \left( k \right)}{k^{2N-1}}} \right|\leqslant \sum_{k=2}^N{\frac{1}{k^N}}+\sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^2}}<\sum_{k=2}^N{\frac{\varepsilon}{2^{k-1}}}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2^N}=\varepsilon 
\end{align*}
By utilizing that cauchy stuff (name forgotten) and the basic definition of limits.
Then, we are done.

Comment: I can kind of see what you did there, but I am still confused, could you make a more rigorous answer please.

Comment: @BlackEmperor Done!

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, I am stuck.

The second one is quite simple since

$$S_k(x)=\sum_{r=1}^{k-1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k+r}}{\left(2k-2r-1\right)!} x^r$$is
$$S_k(x)=(-1)^k \left((-x)^{k-\frac{1}{2}} \sinh
   \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{-x}}\right)-\frac{\,
   _1F_2\left(1;k,k+\frac{1}{2};-\frac{1}{4 x}\right)}{(2 k-1)!}\right)$$
$$S_k(1)=-\sin(1)-\frac{(-1)^k \,
   _1F_2\left(1;k,k+\frac{1}{2};-\frac{1}{4}\right)}{\Gamma (2 k)}$$

Notice that for $k>0$
$$\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} J_{\frac{1}{2}}(1)\leq \,
   _1F_2\left(1;k,k+\frac{1}{2};-\frac{1}{4}\right) < 1$$ expalins the very fast convergence.

Neglecting the hypergeometric function
$$S_k(x) \sim -x^{k-\frac{1}{2}} \sin \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)$$