# A conjecture involving series with zeta function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, summation, taylor-expansion, power-series

Recently, I tried to evaluate [a limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4759687) proposed by MSE user Black Emperor. In the process of evaluating the limit, I have obtained the following equality.
$$
\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^{N-2}{\frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n}{\left( 2n+1 \right) !}\zeta \left( N-n \right)}=\sin\left(1\right)
$$
But I believe this can applied to a broader case of limits.
Namely, if we have a function $f$ that is holomorphic around zero with a infinite radius of convergence. The following should hold
\begin{align*}
\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^{N-2}{\frac{1}{n!}\zeta \left( N-n \right)}f^{\left( n \right)}\left( 0 \right) 
=&\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^{N-2}{\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{k^n}{k^N}}}f^{\left( n \right)}\left( 0 \right) 
\\
=&\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-2}{\frac{1}{n!}f^{\left( n \right)}\left( 0 \right) k^n}}
\\
=&\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{k^N}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n!}f^{\left( n \right)}\left( 0 \right) k^n}}
\\
=&\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{f\left( k \right)}{k^N}}=f\left( 1 \right) 
\end{align*}
I have verified this result numerically for a some functions, and it seems that this equality holds for functions like:
$\mathbb{sin}\left(x\right)$, $\mathbb{cos}\left(x\right)$, $\mathbb{exp}\left(x\right)$, $\mathbb{sinh}\left(x\right)$, $\mathbb{cosh}\left(x\right)$, $\sqrt{x+1}$, $\mathbb{arctan}\left(x\right)$, $\mathbb{ln}\left(x\right)$, $\mathbb{erf}\left(x\right)$.
However, it did no longer work when I plugged $\mathrm{W}\left(x\right)$ in the Lambert W function.

I have three question here.

1. Is this correct?
2. As you can see, much of the examples **do not** have a infinite radius of convergence, yet, the equality still holds. Therefore, What's the ture criteria of this equality?
3. Can we generalize this equality to a bigger family of functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Tannery's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannery%27s_theorem) to get a sufficient condition. Your sum is $$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{N - 2} {\zeta (N - n)\frac{{f^{(n)} (0)}}{{n!}}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\chi _{\left[ {0 \le n \le N - 2} \right]} \zeta (N - n)\frac{{f^{(n)} (0)}}{{n!}}} 
$$ and we have $$
\left| {\chi _{\left[ {0 \le n \le N - 2} \right]} \zeta (N - n)\frac{{f^{(n)} (0)}}{{n!}}} \right| \le 2\frac{{|f^{(n)} (0)|}}{{n!}}.
$$ Thus, the absolute convergence of the Maclaurin series of $f(x)$ at $x=1$ is enough.

Comment: By using this theorem, seems like it doesn't need to be zeta function as long as it's something bounded along the positive reals, right? (Given the same condition of f)

Comment: Yes, and it has to tend to $1$ as $N\to+\infty$.